# Why does Stack Overflow not take the text inside "<>"?

Tags: discussion

As I am new to Stack Overflow I have posted a question with including text inside "<>". But after some time only I noticed that the text inside this syntax is not in the question.

For example:

I tried to put a question as in [this link].

But question appears as follows

```
curl -v -X POST --basic -u : -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' -k -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Comment: The site has extensive docs on everything, including formatting https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Because it looks like HTML tags and the browser hid it. Use `code formatting` by starting lines with four spaces, or wrapping text in backticks.

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068951/what-do-entities-lt-and-gt-stand-for

Comment: Just now looked in to the docs. thank you

Comment: Although it is a duplicate, I don't see the reason to downvote it. The question is clear and OP obviously didn't notice the connection between `<>` and html tags, therefore he was not able to find existing answers. This question (and many others) will appear in search results and will guide future readers who judge the problem in the same way. So why downvote it?

Comment: thanks Alexandru Severin. Actually I am new to stack over flow. Before I have put a question with those tag (<>) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44353385/curl-command-to-java-http-request]. I didn't notice that the text inside of (<>) are not appearing in the question, after someone put downvote only I noticed that my question is wrong. Then I have edit that question and put a comment. So that I search for the reason. As you said I didn't notice the connection between( <> )and html tags.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it can be read as an HTML tag.

TessellatingHeckler is right. Use backticks or click the icon above the editor for HTML.

Check this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkRVG.jpg

Comment: I have understood it now. Thank you

Comment: good job bro :)